# Export an image at 1000 dpi

Tags: export, image

I'm trying to export an image at 1000 dpi. The author guide of a lot of papers wants this resolution! Then I must to import this image in Word in a small box; let's say 7x4 cm. This is the code that I made and the relative image:

```
grayColorList = (Blend[{Black, White}, #] & /@ Range[0, 1, 0.1]);
histogram = 
Labeled[Histogram[{dataBr[[All, 1]], datacl[[All, 1]], 
dataFCl[[All, 1]], dataF[[All, 1]]}, ChartLayout -> "Stacked", 
ChartLegends -> {"Br-derivatives", "Cl-derivatives", 
 "F+Cl+Br-derivatives", "F-derivatives"}, 
ChartStyle -> {grayColorList[[1]], grayColorList[[4]], 
 grayColorList[[7]], grayColorList[[9]]}], {Rotate[
Style["Relative Frequency", 12], 90 Degree], 
"\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(Exp\)]\)"}, {Left, Bottom}, 
FrameMargins -> {{-8, 0}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image: Image1]

This is a very nice image, but when I try to Export it

```
Export["Histogram.Tif", histogram, ImageResolution -> 1000]
```

This is the result:
[image]

And this is very ugly image!
I've read the other similar posts but I can't find the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to set a specific `ImageSize` for your graphics.

Comment: If i understand this all correctly, you essentially need an image that is 2756x1575 pixels in size.

Answer (score 12):

This problem is essentially because the new-in-9 legending functionality does not produce `Graphics` objects.  It produces something similar to `Row` (i.e. with an underlying `RowBox`) that joins the `Graphics` and the legend.  This is a generic object that can be displayed in a notebook but cannot be manipulated as conveniently as `Graphics` objects.

This tends to break my workflow too and I can't do a number of things I could easily do with Graphics (e.g. export to a specific size) ... I wish legended graphics were still proper `Graphics`.

Fortunately, as rm-rf said, in this case the solution is easy: just use the `ImageSize` option in `Histogram` with a numeric argument (i.e. not `Automatic`).  For example, use `ImageSize -> 360` which is the same as the default.  Now exporting at higher resolution won't change the relative size of the graphics and the legend.

Comment: Thanks a lot! very useful comment...